# install matplotlib using pip error(with raspberry pi 3b)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pip

I cant't install matplotlib. I'm using a raspberry pi 3b.

I am using this

```
pip --no-cache-dir install matplotlib
```

to install matplotlib. At the start it is all ok. But in *last* part,
I get this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", 
line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", 
line 784, in install
**kwargs
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 
345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 
316, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", 
line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/backports.functools_lru_cache-1.5.dist-info'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sudo -H pip install matplotlib` if you want to install it system wide or create a virualenv and use `pip install matplotlib` to install it on a virtualenv.

Comment: not work it shows:

Comment: it have MEMORYERROR

Comment: The error log you posted shows a permission error when trying to create a directory. Are you having a different error when trying with `sudo`?

Comment: look likes it could but it was slow

Comment: so did it install?